# Angular 2 : Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Tags: angular, events, binding, scope, eventemitter

I am new to Angular 2 and I am trying to bind an "onclick" event to a #sitenav object in a parent component/template.

**menu.html (Child template)**

```
<md-list-item *ngFor="let entry of entries">
    <button md-menu-item  (click)="sidenav.close()">
      <md-icon>{{entry.icon}}</md-icon>
      <span><a routerLink="{{entry.route}}">{{entry.link}}</a></span>
    </button>
</md-list-item>
```

**menu.ts (Child template component file)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'navlinks',
    templateUrl: 'menubtn.component.html'
})
export class MenuBtnComponent {
    entries = [];

@Output() buttonClicked : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

   close(value:any){
    this.buttonClicked.emit("close");
   }

  constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
    this.entries = [
        {
            icon: 'home',
            route: '/',
            link:  'Home'
        },
        {
            icon: 'sentiment_satisfied',
            route: '/about',
            link:  'About Us'
        },
        {
            icon: 'content_paste',
            route: '/work',
            link:  'Out Work'
        },
        {
            icon: 'mail',
            route: '/contact',
            link:  'Get In Touch'
        },
    ];

   }
}
```

**sitenav.ts (parent template component)**

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, Directive} from '@angular/core';
import { MdMenuModule, MdMenuTrigger} from '@angular/material';

import { MenuBtnComponent } from './menubtn.component';


@Component({
  moduleId:module.id,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  selector: 'sitenav',
  templateUrl: './sitenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './sitenav.component.css']
})
export class SitenavComponent {
 clickedButton(val){
    console.log(val);
 }
}
```

**sitenav.html (parent template)**

```
 <!--sidenav-->
  <md-sidenav  
    #sidenav 
    class="app-sidenav md2 md-sidenav md-sidenav-side md-sidenav-closed"
    mode="side">
    <md-list flex="" role="list" class="flex">
      <navlinks (buttonClicked)="close($event)"></navlinks>
    </md-list>
  </md-sidenav>
 <!--//sidenav-->
```

The `(click)="sidenav.close()"` close #sitenav upon clicking, however it does not seem to be visible from the menu.html template so I am getting the error:

```
Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
```

How do I bin close to #sidenav?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the parent components method from the child directly. Output() parameter is the best way to achieve your requirement.

You code has to be modified as

```
    import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'navlinks',
    templateUrl: 'menubtn.component.html'
})
export class MenuBtnComponent {
    @Output() buttonClicked : EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
    entries = [];

  constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        ....

   }
   close(value:any){
    this.buttonClicked.emit("close");
   }
}
```

Your HTML markup should be

```
 <md-list-item *ngFor="let entry of entries">
        <button md-menu-item  (buttonClicked)="close($event)">
      <md-icon>{{entry.icon}}</md-icon>
      <span><a routerLink="{{entry.route}}">{{entry.link}}</a></span>
    </button>
</md-list-item>
```

You parent component should be as

```
<md-list-item *ngFor="let entry of entries">
        <button md-menu-item  (buttonClicked)="close($event)">
          <md-icon>{{entry.icon}}</md-icon>
          <span><a routerLink="{{entry.route}}">{{entry.link}}</a></span>
        </button>
</md-list-item>
```

Parent component ts file should have the below method

```
 clickedButton(val){
    console.log(val);
 }
```

Note: The way in which you are accessing the close() method is valid for the reverse case. **ChildComponent** methods from **ParentComponent** 
It is pretty obvious that #sideNav is not related to the child component and how you can access the close() method?

Comment: HTML markup and parent component are the same in your code?

Comment: I have updated the code above but nothing happens. No errors. Shouldn't  `<md-sidenav` (parent) be listening for the event>

Comment: And how is it particularly targetting the #sidenav element to close it?

Comment: Have not used it before, any alternatives?

Comment: google remote desktop. I can fix your problem remotely

Comment: I will be back at my desktop in 30mins. Would you be able to use plunker instead?

Comment: ok, but your code is concerned about the **navlinks** or? @HGB, come back and notify me.

Comment: I am back at my desk and have updated my code with yours above. However when I add `(buttonClicked)="close($event)"` to my child button, nothing happens and when I go back to `(click)="sidenav.close()"` It brings up the error again. I really don't understand why it is so complicated just to target the #sidenav element from the `menu.html` template.

Comment: are you available in teamviewer? or remote connection? I can fix it in few mins instead of lengthy conv

Comment: What's your teamviewer ID?

Comment: @HGB shared in the chat

Answer (score 0):

One other possible way of doing this is by a Event bus Service

**eventbusservice.ts**

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class EventBusService
{
    bus:Subject<Event> = new Subject<Event>();

    dispatch(data:Event){
        this.bus.next(data);
    }

    listen(type:string):Observable<Event> {
       return this.bus.filter(event=>event.type === type);
    }
}
```

**menu.ts**

```
  import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
  import { EventBusService } from './eventbusservice'
@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'navlinks',
    templateUrl: 'menubtn.component.html'
})
export class MenuBtnComponent {
    entries = [];

  constructor(private eventbus:EventBusService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        ....

   }
   close(){
    this.eventbus.dispatch("close");
   }
}
```

**sitenav.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {EventBusService} from './eventbusservice'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'site-nav',
    templateUrl: 'sitenav.html'
})
export class SiteNavComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private eventbus:EventBusService) {
this.eventbus.listen("close").subscribe((e)=>{this.closeSomething()})

     }
closeSomething(){

}
    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**menu.html**

```
<md-list-item *ngFor="let entry of entries">
    <button md-menu-item  (click)="close()">
      <md-icon>{{entry.icon}}</md-icon>
      <span><a routerLink="{{entry.route}}">{{entry.link}}</a></span>
    </button>
</md-list-item>
```

***This process helps when change in one component has impact on many
other components(not just parent component).***

Comment: Interesting. Is there a reason to not use a Bus Service? I have just started with Angular 2 and want to keep as close to the standards as possible, can eventbusservice.ts be imported every time you need to listen for an event on any component?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Thanks Sai, but would you be able to tell what's wrong with my method above using the EventEmitter option?